# Accessing Service Definition File (.sd) properties without publishing?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-rest-api, service-definition

Is it possible to "open" or read a service definition file (.sd) using ArcPy, ArcGIS REST API, or some other method? I have a number of .sd files that I'd like to interrogate for their properties. I'm mainly interested in seeing which data sources went into the service definition, but I'm not clear on how to access the properties of a service definition file.

Comment: Have you tried opening in a text editor? I think they're XML, though there may be a zip involved.